# Testing server timeout

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, tdd, chai

I'm trying to write a test with Mocha, Chai and Supertest to check if a backend API throw a timeout error.

I'd like to have something like this

```
describe("timeout call", () => {
    it("should return error 408", async () => {
        await supertest(app).get(url)
            .expect(408)
    });
});
```

since the timeout error doesn't depend on parameters I pass to the API (it could occur if the user has a slow connection, for example), I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: Typically, you wouldn't want to run a unit test on a real backend API. You would rather mock the request.

Comment: Basically, this API class an API on another project and returns the result (next will be the result will be used in some way). I'd like to add a failing test to check timeout in some way